# Display Sqlite Data in Uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite

Sorry I tried it out myself but couldn't find the solution
I have the following code in my viewdidload method

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
docsDir=[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"database.db"]];

NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==YES)
{


[self getFinal];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"please order");
}
[super viewDidLoad];
```

It calls a method called as getFinal
which is as follows

```
 sqlite3_stmt  *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath,&database)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM FINALORDER"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];     
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt,-1,&statement,NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *itemname = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];
        //itemn.text = itemname;

        NSString *qua = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];
        //quantity.text = qua;

        NSString *total = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];
        //totalcost.text=total;
    }


}
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

I want to display the itemname, qua and total in a tableview format. I have tried using the protocols and implementing the delegate as well as the data source methods but data source method cellforindexpath doesn't recognize those variables, how am I supposed to do that? thanks
here is the code for the table view

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
  //I DONT KNOW WHAT TO RETURN HERE..
   }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = itemname  //i need to get the itemname here
cell.detailTextLabel.text = qua,total //i need the quantity and the totalcost values   

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use Core Data or at least [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as a layer between you and the database for clarity and simplicity.

Now for the TableView problem, it would be nice if you could post some code as well.

Comment: well its too late to change everything to core data,i have no knowledge in it so i had to use sqlite3,but in numberrowsinsection what am i supposed to take as a variable to count??

Comment: for numberrowsinsection, it is the number of cells in your table, what is that supposed to be?

Comment: well i have another view controller where the user orders some dishes along with the quantity,now the view which i have posted above only has to retrieve those items which user has selected..so how am i supposed to know the number of rows?

Comment: You have to pass that information from the other viewcontroller. If you use Storyboard, you can use segues between your viewcontrollers and pass information that way.

Comment: well i am little confused now..anyways thanks for the help i will try figuring it out..and i am not using xcode 4 so i cant use storyboards..:-(

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `itemName` etc. as local variables within a scope not visible to your data source methods. You need to save them as instance variables of your view controller.

Comment: hey thanks that was so silly..but anyways what am i supposed to return in numberofrows??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code :

```
NSString *itemname, *qua, *total;
```

Inside Function:

```
sqlite3_stmt  *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, & database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM FINALORDER"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

       while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

          itemname = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];
          qua = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];
          total = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];
       }
    }
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
[tblView reloadData];
```

Comment: is tblview an uitableview object?

Comment: what am i supposed to use as the variable for counting the number of rows?

Comment: yes. It will reload or refresh data after getting from database.

Comment: For that, you have take an array. then add to code in while loop
eg.

 [listOfItems addObject:itemname];

Then, Method:
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listOfItems count];
}

Comment: ok will it not work if i include the protocols,i dont want to subclass tableviewcontroller

Comment: am i supposed to create arrays for the other two variables too? qua and total?

Comment: sure i will try your method and thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have take an array. then add to code in while loop
eg.

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[listOfItems addObject:itemname];
```

Then, Method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [listOfItems count]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try This one it might be help you

    +(NSMutableArray*)getData
    {
        NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/DBEmployee.sqlite",NSHomeDirectory()];
        sqlite3 *db;
        NSMutableArray   *empArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if(sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String] , &db)  == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM Employee";
            char* err_msg;
            sqlite3_stmt* statement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1,&statement, &err_msg) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    DatabaseKeys *emp = [[DatabaseKeys alloc]init];
                    emp.Eno = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                    NSString *strn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",emp.Eno];
                    [empArr addObject:strn];


                }
            }
        }
        return empArr;
    }
```